# The [msgpack] and [messagepack] tags are duplicates

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Both [msgpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msgpack) and [messagepack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/messagepack) refer to the same topic and have the same tag-info.

I'm picking synonym-request over retag-request for the following reasons:

- The name of the addressed library is "MessagePack", which is reflected by [messagepack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/messagepack),
- "msgpack" is the well known abbreviation (f.e. used as domain-name) of MessagePack,

and therefore I suggest to make [msgpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msgpack) a synonym of [messagepack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/messagepack) to correctly reflect the name-dependency.

Comment: This was done by Oded on March 1st 2017.